# SQL Where statement that matches words with different order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I have the following mysql code:

```
SELECT * FROM top_movies WHERE genre LIKE '%$genre%'
```

$genre is a string such as 'Comedy Drama'

and genre column in the database has strings such as Comedy Drama.

If $genre is Comedy Drama it will match to Comedy Drama.
But also i want it to match to Drama Comedy.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

NOTE: $genre is a dynamic variable, i dont know how many words it contain, in what order or which words it has.

NOTE2: I am using PHP so any operations with PHP is welcomed.

Comment: The best way to do is to restructure your table, make it many-to-many relationship since movie can have multiple genre and at the same time genre belongs to multiple movies. In that way, you can easily search for genre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in php you should split the genres into words

`$genre = explode($genre," ")`

and $genre becomes and array, each element containing one word

ad you should do

```
$query = ""
foreach $genre as $element
{
  if (strlen($query) > 1)
  {
    $query += "AND "
  }
  $query += "genre LIKE  %"+$element + "% "
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM top_movies WHERE " + $query
```

this way it searches for each individual element in genre no matter the order